# Why does the removal of this return statement affect the outcome of the entire recursive function?

Tags: c++, string, function, recursion, palindrome

I am writing a palindrome checker using recursion. 
I am confused to why removing the

```
return true
```

Statement at the end of the function affects the return value.

```
int firstChar = 0;
int lastChar = 0;
// These two variables are used to transverse the string from both ends 
// eventually meeting
```

Code #1:

```
bool palindromeCheck (string text, int firstChar, int lastChar)
{
    string tempCleanText = text;

    // Removes all punctation and space
    if (firstChar == 0)
    {
        // Cleans text, ignore.
        tempCleanText = cleanString(tempCleanText);

        // Sets this variable to the end of the string
        lastChar = tempCleanText.size() - 1;
    }

    // Base Case
    if (firstChar >= lastChar)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (tempCleanText.at(firstChar) == tempCleanText.at(lastChar))
    {
        palindromeCheck(tempCleanText, ++firstChar, --lastChar);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;    // Keeping this in works
}
```

This returns true, as it should for all palindromes, and false for all non-palindromes.

Code #2:

```
bool palindromeCheck (string text, int firstChar, int lastChar)
{
    string tempCleanText = text;

    // Removes all punctation and space.
    if (firstChar == 0)
    {
        // Cleans text, ignore.
        tempCleanText = cleanString(tempCleanText);

        // Sets this variable to the end of the string
        lastChar = tempCleanText.size() - 1;
    }

    // Base Case
    if (firstChar >= lastChar)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (tempCleanText.at(firstChar) == tempCleanText.at(lastChar))
    {
        palindromeCheck(tempCleanText, ++firstChar, --lastChar);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

    // there is no return true here, and so the output is no longer correct
}
```

This returns true, for only some of the palindromes, and false for all non-palindromes.

Palindromes, such as,

amanaplanacanalpanama <- size length 21

Returns false, when it should return true.

Through testing, it is shown that the base case is entered using the last palindrome, meaning that the function sees it as a valid palindrome. But, I'm assuming the program then unwinds the call stack and as it goes through all the previous function calls, something makes the function return false.

Comment: `bool palindromeCheck (string text, int firstChar, int lastChar)` promises that the function will return a `bool`. If you break that promise the compiler can [really, really make you pay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You never want to exit a function with a non-`void` return type without returning a suitable value.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings and address them before testing functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters the function is in any case incorrect. For example for the string `"1231"` the function returns `true`. I hope you can check this yourself.

This part of the function

```
if (tempCleanText.at(firstChar) == tempCleanText.at(lastChar))
{
    palindromeCheck(tempCleanText, ++firstChar, --lastChar);
}
else
{
    return false;
}

return true;    // Keeping this in works
```

should be at least substituted for the following code snippet

```
if (tempCleanText.at(firstChar) == tempCleanText.at(lastChar))
{
    return palindromeCheck(tempCleanText, ++firstChar, --lastChar);
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

That is this return statement

```
return true;    // Keeping this in works
```

shall be entirely removed.

As for your question then without the last return statement the function have undefined behavior because it returns nothing after the if statement. That is the if statement

```
if (tempCleanText.at(firstChar) == tempCleanText.at(lastChar))
{
    palindromeCheck(tempCleanText, ++firstChar, --lastChar);
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

successfully was executed provided that

```
tempCleanText.at(firstChar) == tempCleanText.at(lastChar))
```

and what does the function return after executing the sub-statement of the if statement? Nothing! :)

Also it does not make sense to declare two additional parameters (indices) apart from the string itself because in any case the string is passed by value and you always can get its size by calling the member function `size()`.

I can suggest the following implementation of the function Similarly to your function this function implementation returns true in case when an empty string is passed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

bool palindromeCheck( std::string s )
{
    if ( s.size() < 2 )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if ( ispunct( ( unsigned char )s.front() ) || isspace( ( unsigned char )s.front() ) )
    {
        return palindromeCheck( s.substr( 1 ) );
    }
    else if ( ispunct( ( unsigned char )s.back() ) || isspace( ( unsigned char )s.back() ) )
    {
        return palindromeCheck( s.substr( 0, s.size() - 1 ) );
    }
    else if ( s.front() == s.back() )
    {
        return s.size() == 2 ? true : palindromeCheck( s.substr( 1, s.size() - 2) ); 
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << palindromeCheck( "" ) << '\n';
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << palindromeCheck( "1" ) << '\n';
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << palindromeCheck( "1 1" ) << '\n';
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << palindromeCheck( "1,2,2,1" ) << '\n';
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << palindromeCheck( "1 2 3 2 1" ) << '\n';
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << palindromeCheck( "12341" ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
true
true
true
true
true
false
```

Comment: @JaMiT I doubt that the author of the question knows already about C++ 17.:) I tried to present an implementation using his approach.

Answer (score 1):

may be

```
// ...

if (tempCleanText.at(firstChar) == tempCleanText.at(lastChar))

{
   return palindromeCheck(tempCleanText, ++firstChar, --lastChar); 
}

else
    return false;
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Returning from a non-void function without explicitly returning a value via the `return` keyword invokes *undefined behavior*.  Per the C++ spec, a program that invokes undefined behavior is free to do literally anything at all, and all blame for any resulting weirdness will be placed at the feet of the programmer that wrote the code that invoked the undefined behavior.

What's likely actually happening in this case is that when your function returns by dropping off the end of the function (and doesn't do a `return false`), the location where the function's return-value was stored simply never gets written to -- which means that, as far as the calling code is concerned, the value returned by your function will be equal to whatever value happened to be present at that location when your function returns.  The pre-existing value at that location will be arbitrary and hard-to-predict, since it is a result of various details regarding how the program executes, and therefore the behavior of the program will be arbitrary and hard-to-predict as well.

The solution is to be sure to always explicitly return a value; enabling warnings in your compiler will allow it to help you in that task by warning you if you ever forget to return a value in some code-path.